# Search Bar using React Native

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to add a searchbar from `react-native-searchbar` to filter a list, like so, but it throws an error:

> deputies is not defined.

I don't know what I should do from here, sorry, very new at RN! The data comes from a meteor app.

```
class Flat_List extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this._handleResults = this._handleResults.bind(this);
    this.state = { dataSource : { deputies } };
  }

    _handleResults(results){
    this.setState({dataSource: this.props.deputies(results)})
  }

   render(){
    const {deputies}= this.props; // the list is here

    return(
      <View>

        <SearchBar
          ref={(ref) => this.searchBar = ref}
          data={deputies}
          handleResults={this._handleResults.bind(this)}
          showOnLoad
          allDataOnEmptySearch
          hideBack
          autoCorrect= {false}
        />

        <List>
          <FlatList
            data={this.props.deputies}
            keyExtractor={(item)=> item._id}
            renderItem={({item})=>(
             <DeputyDetail deputy={item.depute} navigation={this.props.navigation} /> )} />
        </List>

      </View>
    );
  }
export default createContainer(params => {
  Meteor.subscribe('deputies');
  return { deputies: Meteor.collection('deputies').find() };
}, Flat_List);
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the parent of `Flat_List` / it's invocation site? It's likely that you are not passing `props` accurately since they are not defined, but it's easier to debug if we can see the parent component.

Comment: Actually this is the parent, the data comes from 
    export default createContainer(params=>{
      Meteor.subscribe('deputies');
     return{
    deputies: Meteor.collection('deputies').find(),
};
},Flat_List);

Comment: Ok, you'll want to start by ensuring that `this.props.deputies` is arriving by the time `render` gets called. If it is not, it won't be defined. That's your first step. You can add a check that the data arrives using the ternary operator `this.props.deputies ? this.props.deputies : ["Data not arrived"]` - if it does not arrive, it will be undefined at the time `render is called`. There are a few other issues with the code, but start there!

Comment: Alright, I will try that. Should I put the expressions just after render() , like so this.props.deputies ? this.props.deputies : ["Data not arrived"] ?

Comment: Yes, put it in as your first line in `render` and `console.log` it out right after.

Comment: It renders the full list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161338/discussion-between-parker-ziegler-and-sonia).

Answer (score 0):

Your state declaration is invalid. Add/edit these lines in your constructor():

```
const { deputies } = this.props;
this.state={
  dataSource: deputies
}
```

Comment: it says "deputies is not defined"

Comment: Can you show us how you are passing `deputies` into your `<Flat_List />` component?

Comment: I connect RN to Meteor app from this component like this : export default createContainer(params => {
  Meteor.subscribe('deputies');
  return { deputies: Meteor.collection('deputies').find() };
}, Flat_List);

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props){

   super(props);
   this._handleResults = this._handleResults.bind(this);
   this.state={
      dataSource : {deputies} // Here -> You doesn't define deputies
   }
}
```

Only add this line before `this.state`:

```
const { deputies } = props // You don't need 'this' because 'props' is already in the constructor params.
```

Or you can put it directly -> `this.state{ dataSource: props.deputies }`

Comment: Or you can put it directly -> this.state{ dataSource: props.deputies }

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing this props to this component?